# Getting all markers from database to map

Tags: android, database, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have stored places in the database with their Longitude and Latitude, and i want to get the Latlngs for all the places and show them on Google Map v2.

I tried to put a test marker in the OnCreate function, but it dose not work, maybe because i put it in a wrong place ?

Here is my code: (the code works without the part of the add marker):

```
public class NearbyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,OnInfoWindowClickListener, 
 GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
 GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 private LocationManager locationManager;
 private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
 private GoogleMap map;
 private LocationClient mLocationClient;

 private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

// Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // Global field to contain the error dialog
    private Dialog mDialog;

    // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
    public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        super();
        mDialog = null;
    }

    // Set the dialog to display
    public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = dialog;
    }

    // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDialog;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map = mapFragment.getMap();

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
// This is working byt with fixed values not from database..
        Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(26.2412591, 50.5961323))
    .title("0000")
    .snippet("Manama Capital of Arab Tourism")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.palace)));

    onInfoWindowClick(melbourne);
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyActivity.this,Description.class);
         intent.putExtra("id", "klkl");
         startActivity(intent);
                  } });
// end of add marker.

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    if(isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()){
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

}

/*
 * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

/*
 * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
 * by Google Play services
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
                int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Decide what to do based on the original request code
    switch (requestCode) {

        case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    mLocationClient.connect();
                    break;
            }

    }
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
        return true;
    } else {
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog( resultCode,
                                                                                                              this,
                                                                                                              CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {
            // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
        }

        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
 * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
 * request the current location or start periodic updates
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
 * location client drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
 * Location Services fails.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
            * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
            * PendingIntent
            */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry. Location services not available to you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nearby, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the marker in onResume().  I'm surprised you're not getting a null pointer exception on map.setMyLocationEnabled(true), because in my experience, the map in a map fragment is not instantiated until onStart.  Therefore you can't add markers to it in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all your database values to  a list: example a store list with latitude and longitude. Then you have to add each and every marker to the map in this way (below code handles the click also):

```
private final void addLocationsToMap() {
        int i = 0;
        for (Stores store : storeList) {
            LatLng l = new LatLng(store.getLatitude(), store.getLongtitude());

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(l)
                    .title(store.getStoreName())
                    .snippet("" + i)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            ++i;
        }

        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                try {
                    popUpWindow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Stores store = storeList.get(Integer.parseInt(marker
                            .getSnippet()));

                    // set details
                    email.setText(store.getEmail());
                    phoneNo.setText(store.getPhone());
                    address.setText(store.getAddress());

                    // setting test value to phone number
                    tempString = store.getPhone();
                    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
                    spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0,
                            spanString.length(), 0);
                    phoneNo.setText(spanString);

                    // setting test value to email
                    tempStringemail = store.getEmail();

                    SpannableString spanString1 = new SpannableString(tempStringemail);
                    spanString1.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString1.length(), 0);
                    email.setText(spanString1);

                    storeLat = store.getLatitude();
                    storelng = store.getLongtitude();

                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    Log.e("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", " Occured");
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should draw marker in onResume(), and you must be sure check the map != null before operate it.